# Generated bug data script how not to set the IDENTITY in the insert statements?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-sql-database

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to generate sql script (big one) 
to update Azure DB. 
The problem is that the script is generated with `IDENTITY` on and the insert statements are exported with the ID column which as result gives me the errors :

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table_Name' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

My question is how to generate the script right that is will not use  `IDENTITY` on and the insert.

Answer (score 6):

[bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) is probably a better way to achieve this and works well with Azure SQL Database.  It's a command-line tool that enables you to extract and  load data easily.  For example:

```
bcp "dbo.yourTable" out c:\temp\temp.bcp -S "yourSourceServer" -d "yourSourceDatabase" -T -n

bcp "dbo.yourTable" in c:\temp\temp.bcp -S "yourTargeteServer" -d "yourTargetDatabase" -U someSQLLogin -P somePassword -E -n
```

Specify the `-E` switch in the `bcp in` statement to keep your `IDENTITY` values.  Replace the table, server and database names in my template above and see if you can get the first statement to run.  Note in the first example I am using Windows Authentication (`-T`) but SQL Authentication in the second one (`-U` for User and `-P` for password).  The main MSDN page for bcp provides some good examples:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

If your table already has some data in it, consider inserting your data into a staging table first, then `INSERT` to your main table, eg

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTargetTable ON
GO

INSERT INTO yourTargetTable ( columnList )
SELECT columnList
FROM yourStagingTable s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM yourTargetTable t
    WHERE s.yourPrimaryKey = t.yourPrimaryKey
    )
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTargetTable OFF
GO
```

There are other methods of achieving this.

- For example, you could accomplish the same thing using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) but there is some overhead to creating an SSIS project.
- For example, if your table is not too big, create a copy of your table in tempdb using something like `SELECT [all columns except the identity column] INTO tempdb.dbo.scratchTable FROM yourMainTable`.  Run the `Generate Scripts` option against this copy then delete your scratch table.